# Double transition bug tvOS

Tags: swift, tvos

I have transition bug on tvOS platform: When I push "enter" button on remote control twice I have double transition to next view controller. I've fixed this problem on ios like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    var segueInProgress: Bool?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationController?.delegate = self
    }

    override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        return segueInProgress == false
    }

    func navigateShow(to viewController: UIViewController, sender: Any? = self) {
        if self.segueInProgress == true { return }

        if let navigationController = self.navigationController {
            navigationController.show(viewController, sender: sender)
        } else {
            self.show(viewController, sender: sender)
        }
    }

    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        // Or like this: self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        self.segueInProgress = true
    }

    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, didShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        self.segueInProgress = false
        // Or like this: self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }
}
```

But on tvOS this solution doesn't work and I don't know why. When I make double click to fast I have several transitions. Please help

```
let detailVC: DetailViewController = DetailViewController.instantiateViewController()
navigateShow(to: detailVC)
```

Comment: Is there some other code that triggers `navigateShow()`function? How do you call it?

Comment: I've added in the end of description. I try to add some static var and its working. but I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

You could disable the button after the press which would prevent the user from double pressing and just make sure that if you need to worry about state coming back to your ViewController you enable it back on viewWillAppear.

Comment: It is not flexible suggestion. Also it could make a lot of extra code.